# Stored procedures with auto increment - Column count exception

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, auto-increment

I have a table with a auto incremented id. The id is also a foreign key in another table. When I try to add values to these tables I get an exception - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

These are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Hotspot(
num int auto_increment not null,
id varchar(255),
x int,
y int,
width int,
height int,

UNIQUE(id),
PRIMARY KEY (num)
);



CREATE TABLE Hotspot_Label(
num int auto_increment not null,
question_id varchar(255),
hotspot_id varchar(255),
label_id varchar(255),


PRIMARY KEY (num),

FOREIGN KEY (hotspot_id)
REFERENCES Hotspot(id),

FOREIGN KEY (label_id)
REFERENCES Label(id),

FOREIGN KEY (question_id)
REFERENCES Question(id)

);
```

This is the stored procedure for one of the tables

```
PROCEDURE `insertHotspot`(IN recID varchar(255), x int, y int, width int, height int)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Hotspot VALUES(recID, x, y, width, height);
END
```

I have read that you don't need to insert an auto increment value in the stored procedure so I can't see what's going wrong

Comment: This is one of the many reasons I consider omitting the optional field list after the table name on an INSERT a bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> INSERT INTO Hotspot VALUES(num,recID, x, y, width, height);

It should be like above
You left the column

*Num*

which is auto incremented although it doesn't need any value to be added the column count decreases if you miss it.

Answer (score 0):

Insert queries of the form `INSERT INTO some_table VALUES(field_values);` are treated as `INSERT INTO some_table(full_field_list_in_ddl_defined_order) VALUES (field_values);` This means, as Bala pointed out, your insert is expecting a value for `Hotspot.num`.

It also means, once you fix the field list now, that if someone later adds a new field anywhere but the end of the table the field values you've supplied will no longer align with the appropriate fields... and have no explicit documentation as to which fields they were intended for.